# Is it possible to cache the query if a Laravel ImplicitRouteBinding is done?

Tags: laravel, caching, routes

Only one query is not cached. I was wondering now I know that is because:
**Implicit Route Binding** Can I cache Implicit Route Binding to improve the performance**? Or exist some other way?

I tried route caching but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i understood this right. Sorry if not, let me know in the comments.
You could try reading `Customizing The Resolution Logic` from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding)

Consider your route is:

```
Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
    return $user->email;
});
```

You could add this in your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` in the `boot` method:

```
Route::bind('user', function ($id) {
    return Cache::remember("user_{$id}", now()->addMinutes(60), function () use ($id) {
        return User::find($id);
    }); 
});
```

However, note that this will bind the user for every single route that you define and contains `{user}`.